# How can I fix this error ? days: NaN yearsNaN monthsNaN weeksNaN daysNaN minutesNaN seconds

Tags: angular, date, ionic-framework, time

I'm working on an ionic project, and have this error.
I have have a button , I want print date that user select

My code

age.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from'moment';
@Component({
 .....
})
export class AgeComponent implements OnInit {
dob:any = '' ;
myDate = {
  years: 0,
  months:0,
  weeks:0,
  days:0,
  minutes:0,
  seconds:0,
}
  constructor() { }
  calculateAge(){
      let todaysDate = moment(new Date());
      let dob = moment( new Date(this.dob) );
      let duration = moment.duration(todaysDate.diff(dob));
      this.myDate.years = duration.years();
      this.myDate.months = Math.floor(duration.asMonths());
      this.myDate.weeks = Math.floor(duration.asWeeks());
      this.myDate.days = Math.floor(duration.asDays());
      this.myDate.minutes = Math.floor(duration.asMinutes());
      this.myDate.seconds = Math.floor(duration.asSeconds());
  }
    }
```

And here is my age.component.html code

```
<ion-datetime class="datetime" [(ngModel)]="dob" pickerFormat="MMM DD YYYY" 
displayFormat="MMM DD, YYYY" min="1950-01-01" max="2050-01-01"></ion-datetime>
<ion-button (click)="calculateAge()" >Calculate</ion-button>
  <span>{{myDate.years}} years</span>
  <span>{{myDate.months}} months</span>
  <span>{{myDate.weeks}} weeks</span>
  <span>{{myDate.days}} days</span>
  <span>{{myDate.minutes}} minutes</span>
  <span>{{myDate.seconds}} seconds</span>
```

Comment: Can you replicate this in a stackblitz?

Comment: What do the values for todaysDate and dob return? Are they valid dates? Likewise what is the result for duration

Comment: Hmm.. its little bit weird, I try to replicate the problem on stackblizt but the error not showing up, here's the link [stackblizt](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5-8jpdnp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) the NaN error only happens when u not select date from ion-datetime

Comment: u can simply add condition in your `let dob` to this -> `let dob = moment( new Date(this.dob ? this.dob : todaysDate));` so the NaN error will not show up

Comment: @IdreesSindi no problem, I moved the comment to the answer section if the code is works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NaN error only happens when you not select any date from `ion-datetime`.
to solve that problem you can simply add condition in your variable `let dob` to `let dob = moment( new Date(this.dob ? this.dob : todaysDate));`

TS

```
calculateAge(){
      let todaysDate = moment(new Date());
      let dob = moment( new Date(this.dob ? this.dob : todaysDate)); <-- add condition here
      let duration = moment.duration(todaysDate.diff(dob));
      this.myDate.years = duration.years();
      this.myDate.months = Math.floor(duration.asMonths());
      this.myDate.weeks = Math.floor(duration.asWeeks());
      this.myDate.days = Math.floor(duration.asDays());
      this.myDate.minutes = Math.floor(duration.asMinutes());
      this.myDate.seconds = Math.floor(duration.asSeconds());
}
```

here's the [sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5-8jpdnp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Okay, I accepted as the correct solution Thanks, but I have one more thing please help me,
as you see when I click the button [ calculateAge() ] is calling, and then how can I get numbers of seconds continuously? I meant to increase  seconds automatically